# retrieve access data using sql query in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am doing a project in vb.net, and using access 2003 as back end. i want some way of obtaining the password "pwd" of some particular user having user id as "uid".

the user id is obtained using a ComboBox

Comment: What is the structure of your database? You haven't told us anything about it. Also password recovery is impossible if the database uses hashed passwords.

Comment: the database is created by me only, and nothing big in the password, just a simple text. the table user has fields viz. uid, uname, gender, designation, pwd

Answer (score 0):

Before we begin, you must be aware that "user" is a reserved word.  You should not mane a table with a reserved word.  It causes all sorts of problems.  However, we can deal with that using brackets.

There are many ways to do what you ask, but this is how I usually handle it.

First, you need a data connection.  I'm not sure what CPU platform you are using, if it is a 64bit processor, you will need to go to configuration - and change the Active Solution Platform to "x86".

Second, you need a datset to hold the data. Fill the combobox with data from the dataset.

Aftr selecting the "uid" from the combobox, you will need a way to find only that user.  I suggest a dataview.

This a sample program to accomplish the task.  I have tried it and it does work.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim oleConn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim sql As String
Dim command As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Dim oleAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim UserDataSet As New DataSet
Dim usid As String
Dim x As Integer
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    oleConn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    oleConn.ConnectionString = "provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=<< DATBASE PATH>>"
    sql = "Select * From [User]"
    oleConn.Open()
    command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn)
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    oleAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [User]", oleConn)
    UserDataSet = New DataSet
    oleAdapter.Fill(UserDataSet)
    oleConn.Dispose()
    cmbUid.DataSource = UserDataSet.Tables(0)
    cmbUid.DisplayMember = "uid"
End Sub
Private Sub cmbUid_SelectedValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbUid.SelectedValueChanged
    usid = cmbUid.Text
    FindPWD()
End Sub
Private Sub FindPWD()
    'Create a dataview
    Dim dv As New DataView
    'Associate the dataview to _oDs (Dataset table)
    dv.Table = UserDataSet.Tables(0)
    Dim drv As DataRowView 'Data Row View object to query DataView object
    'Filter based on a combo box value selected
    dv.RowFilter = "[uid] LIKE '" & usid & "'"
    'Retrieve my values returned in the result
    For Each drv In dv
        'clear  textbox first time thru
        If x = 0 Then
            x = 1
            txtPwd.Clear()
        Else
            txtPwd.Text = drv("pwd")
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```