# Linking VB to MS Access Database

Tags: vb.net

I have a project to create an MS Access Database driven, VB application.

I need to use SQL coding, so cant just use the standard add data source.

The database would need to be able to have information accessed from the database as well as being able to add more data through the application.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... hundreds of people would love to help you here but we cant answer general questions like that. We needs specific questions you may have, attempts you have made and need to know specific failures.

Comment: the main question is how do you link a microsoft access database to vb.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you need a place to start looking, instead of what your question is asking. I'll provide a list.

1. Connecting to an MS Access Database (OleDb) See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821765)
2. Referring to your connection string from the config file rather than inside each sub/function. If you have to recompile with a different connection string you only need to change it in one location.
3. Using SQL in VB.NET. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184997/retrieve-access-data-using-sql-query-in-vb-net).

Using SQL in VB.NET is looked down upon because it's essentially an "error-less" string. People use Linq for a lot of their database needs. That might be a little advanced at this stage in the game.

Take the time to become familiar with these procedures, and look up the documentation regarding OleDb class, parameterizing queries, etc.

Comment: are you knowledgeable in vb?

Comment: I have some experience using it. I don't believe your question is relevant to this thread, though. Did you read what I linked in my answer / try anything?

Comment: yes, i was wondering if you would be willing to work on a 1-to-1 basis with me on my project?

Comment: Depends to what degree. I will guide you down the correct path if I know the correct answer to your questions, but I won't hold your hand. You're expected to have some knowledge, and if you don't have the knowledge, you should indulge yourself with the recommendations I've suggested.

Comment: well at the moment i have a decent GUI which has some hard coding such as a login page, with if username = .... and password = ... etc... i just struggle with the actual coding element, I am more business minded than programmer minded

Comment: Don't sell yourself short. You're not just going to magically know how to do something without ever seeing or reading about it. That's why people on this website get so frustrated with people because they don't do enough research on their own. They just give up. I promise what you're trying to do is so easy you will slap yourself once you know how to do it.